# How I can get all colors in OxyPlot?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

I have a one question. I use OxyPlot in WPF, C#. I need to have all colors to MarkerType and MarkerStroke for series. How I can get all colors?

Comment: put your code what you have tried..

Comment: public List<OxyColor> koloryWykresow=new List<OxyColor>
        {
           OxyPlot.OxyColors.Green,
           OxyPlot.OxyColors.IndianRed,
            OxyPlot.OxyColors.Coral,
           OxyPlot.OxyColors.Chartreuse,
           OxyPlot.OxyColors.Peru
          };
         I must change this code lists have only some elements. I can write many colors but this isnt smart solution

Comment: @Mario, can you please give any feedback to my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Green, IndianRed, etc are static fields in static OxyColors class. use [reflection](/questions/tagged/reflection) to read all of them

```
var colors = typeof(OxyColors)
             .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
             .Where(f => f.FieldType == typeof(OxyColor))
             .Select(f => f.GetValue(null))
             .Cast<OxyColor>()
             .ToList();
```

Comment: Having a similar problem I tested this out and it is working fine. [However I am wondering if there is a more elegant solution to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54906806/oxyplot-how-to-bind-all-oxycolors-as-itemsource-of-a-wpf-combobox) (I don't like the idea of creating yet another list of all the colors, when we already have all the information saved in the `OxyColors` class.)

Comment: OxyColors doesn't contain a list. But you can create your own and store it in a `static` property in any relevant class