# OxyPlot: How to bind all OxyColors as itemsource of a WPF combobox?

Tags: c#, wpf, oxyplot

Using OxyPlot, I want to provide the user of my WPF Application with a combobox containing all available OxyColors to select one color.

[From the sourcecode](https://github.com/ylatuya/oxyplot/blob/master/Source/OxyPlot/Foundation/OxyColors.cs), one can see that the OxyColors are `public static readonly`properties of the static `OxyColors` class.

The Question is, if there is a way to bind all colors as itemsource of a combobox. 
The only thing I can think of so far is to create a `List<OxyColor>` and manually add all of the colors to it, but maybe there is a more elegant way to tackle this problem.

Edit: [Found this answer to a similar problem.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602161/how-i-can-get-all-colors-in-oxyplot) However, again it is manually creating a List of all colors.

Comment: There is no "more elegant" way than, one way or another, adding all colours to an `IEnumerable` that you bind to the `ComboBox`.

Comment: You just need to create a custom list ONCE, have it in a XAML resource dictionary, and [re-use it everywhere you want](https://imgur.com/IBYeb0n), FOREVER...:O)

Comment: @jsanalytics thanks for the input. ATM I solved it via reflection within the viewmodel. However since there are several viewmodels for the same usercontrol within my project, this function runs several times (10-20ms each). I will look into a good way to put the list into the apps resource dictionary on startup and only have to run it once.

Comment: Either you have a solution or you don't.... If you do, then you should post it and mark your question as answered.